# How can I add a confirmation Email and Text message to my project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am developing this app for school project. I am new and don't have much experience in Xamarin and C#. In my application I can receive the message as the owner of the app after a form has been submitted. I also need to add the functionality that a user or customer receives a confirmation text and email after submitting the form. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is Xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ICC.RequestServicesPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="50,50,50,50">

            <Entry x:Name="EntryFName"
                    Placeholder="First Name"
                    Keyboard="Text" />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryLName"
                    Placeholder="Last Name"
                    Keyboard="Text" />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryEmail"
                    Placeholder="Email address"
                    Keyboard="Email" />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryPhone"
                    Placeholder="Phone number"
                    Keyboard="Telephone" />

            <Button Text="Submit"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    FontSize="Large"
                Clicked="OnClickSubmit" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

and here is the C# page

```
namespace COOP
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RequestServicesPage : ContentPage
    {

        public RequestServiceFormPage(string service, DateTime date)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        async void OnClickSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //build the message body from the form entries
            //Phone and Address2 are optional, so only add if they are not null
            bool isValid = true;
            string fName = EntryFName.Text;
            string lName = EntryLName.Text;
            string email = EntryEmail.Text;
            string phone = EntryPhone.Text;


            if (email == null || email == "")
            {
                isValid = false;
                EntryEmail.Placeholder = "Email address *";
                EntryEmail.PlaceholderColor = Red;
            }
            else if (!IsValidEmail(email))
            {
                isValid = false;
                EntryEmail.Placeholder = "Enter a valid Email";
                EntryEmail.PlaceholderColor = Red;
                EntryEmail.Text = "";
            }
            if (phone == null || phone == "")
            {
                isValid = false;
                EntryPhone.Placeholder = EntryPhone.Placeholder + " *";
                EntryPhone.PlaceholderColor = Red;
            }
            else if (!IsValidPhone(phone) && phone != null && phone != "")
            {
                isValid = false;
                EntryPhone.Placeholder = "Enter a Valid Phone Number";
                EntryPhone.PlaceholderColor = Red;
                EntryPhone.Text = "";
            }

            //build the message body from the form entries
            if (isValid)
            {
                //add the email address and text address to send the email to
                List<string> address = new List<string>();
                address.Add("test@gmail.com");
                address.Add("9999999999@vtext.com");

                //build the message body from the form entries
                string message = "";
                message += "New " + requestService + " Request from: \n";
                message += EntryFName.Text + " " + EntryLName.Text + "\n";
                message += EntryEmail.Text + "\n";
                message += EntryPhone.Text + "\n";
                message += EntryAddress1.Text + "\n";
                //call send email function. function body is below.
                await SendEmail("Test", message);

            }
        }
        public static bool IsValidPhone(string phoneNumber)
        {

            string numbersOnly = RemoveNonNumeric(phoneNumber);
            if (numbersOnly.Length == 7 || numbersOnly.Length == 10)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static string RemoveNonNumeric(string phone)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(phone, @"[^0-9]+", "");
        }
        public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|" + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)" + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return regex.IsMatch(email);
        }
        public async Task SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> recipients)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = new EmailMessage
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body,
                    To = recipients,
                };
                await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally confirmation e-mails and texts are generated on the server, not from the mobile client.

Comment: @Jason How can I set up the server? Can you give me a website or something to start with! I don't have any knowledge of it. Thank you

Comment: If you are doing this for a project it may not matter if you do it on the client.  You can just add another address to recipients to send mail to an additional person.  If you want to send a text from the device, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/sms?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms

Comment: its not hard to do in node https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp

Comment: @Jason Thanks for helping me out. I actually am looking for something simple, So after the user enters his email address and submits the form, He will get an email like "Here is your confirmation Email" from the owner of the app(test@gmail.com).

Comment: you either need your own e-mail server to do that, or an e-mail service that provides an API, like mailgun (there are many, many to choose from)